# External display has blurry fonts on Dell U2312hm- MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: display, macbook-pro, font

I just bought a new Dell external display (U2312hm) for my MacBook Pro Retina.

The fonts appear to be very blurry. I've searched and found [a solution here](http://embdev.net/topic/284710), but it didn't fix my problem. I ran the script supplied in the thread, followed all instructions and the problem remains (tried on 2 different rMBPs with 2 different U2312hm monitors).

here are real a few examples (the upper browser in each picture is chrome on VMware and the lower is chrome on OSX 10.8.5):
[image]
[image]

I tried different font smoothing configurations which failed to improve the problem.
I tried using Apple's MiniDisplayPort to AVI and MiniDisplayPort to DisplayPort cables - no change.

What can I do?

Comment: Awful choice of sample page for the second sample; couldn't you have found something less unpleasant?

Comment: @YSY: did you fix the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The solution at http://embdev.net/topic/284710 worked for me.

Attach your display, download the updated [patch-edid.rb](http://embdev.net/topic/284710#3214710), run `ruby patch-edid.rb` in Terminal and reboot.  Voila!

Tested and working on both Mountain Lion and Mavericks with two U2713H monitors.

Comment: as I written in the post, this solution doesn't affect the font appearance. the problem remains.

Answer (score 4):

Horray! I found a solution.

I bought the [Apple Mini DisplayPort to DVI converter cable adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0056XME46) instead of using HDMI, and my picture is much more crisp and clear.

[image]

My Retina display is still better, but it's a better screen. my HP monitor is now performing to is ability.  For some reason, HDMI must degrade the video quality.

Comment: This also worked for me. I did not think that there would be a difference between Mini DisplayPort and HDMI. When it comes to connecting a MacbookPro, I guess there is a big difference. The font rendering is still not as crisp as my Ubuntu machine renders on the same monitor, but when comparing the same screen connected to Mini DisplayPort and HDMI, Mini DisplayPort is the clear winner.

Comment: How about an HDMI to DVI adapter? Is it the DVI connection that makes the difference? Or is it the display port connection? It's an important distinction because HDMI to DVI is ~$4 and an Apple-sanctified DisplayPort to DVI is ~$40

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the "Best Resolution for display" setting for the external monitor?  I was forcing 1920x1080 and seeing a similar fuzzy look.  I changed from the fixed resolution to Best Resolution (even tough they are the same), and my fonts are now smooth on my Viewsonic (at work) and my HP (at home) 24" monitors.

Comment: I'm using "Best for display" and still have this problem, I will add a photo to show the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried toggling Use LCD Font Smoothing off and rebooting? To my eyes, it makes fonts on non-Retina displays look super thick and somewhat blurry, not unlike your photos.  It's in System Preferences → General:

[LCD Font Smoothing http://static.command-tab.com/2013/lcd-font-smoothing.png](http://static.command-tab.com/2013/lcd-font-smoothing.png)

Comment: I just took this exact screen shot..!

Comment: unfortunately this setting did not fix the problem (tried changing to bigger font sizes too).

Answer (score 1):

HDMI did not work for me but the  Apple Mini DisplayPort to DVI converter cable adapter
worked perfectly! with a HP Pavilion 25bw

Answer (score 0):

Image here shows a web page from Internet Explorer (top, on Parallels) and on OSX Chrome (Below).
[image]

The problem you saw was not really a problem. It was the different way which Windows and OSX render their fonts (aliasing). Some people prefer Windows's sharp font, others prefer OSX style.

I hope I understood your problem correctly because what you showed in the image(not clear, not a screen capture but from a camera) was what I have noticed before.

See [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html) for a comparison on the two algorithms for aliasing fonts.

Comment: This isn't the problem being described. I know very well the differences in font rendering between the Mac OS X and Windows platforms. 

What's actually happening is a problem with the signal sent from the Mac to the monitor. The Mac is using the wrong color space, and it screws up font rendering, somehow. Forcing the color space to RGB, by using the patch-edid.rb script, has completely altered the font rendering on my external display, from "crunchy" to smooth. 

Good explanation here: http://www.ireckon.net/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor