# Macbook (Late 2016) blurry with Dell s2415h Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, hdmi

When I connect my new MacBook Pro to the Dell s2415h, the text is slightly blurry. I tried the [solution here](http://embdev.net/topic/284710) but it didn't work for me. I also found this [older post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99020/external-display-has-blurry-fonts-on-dell-u2312hm-macbook-pro-retina) which found success with DVI but my Dell only has VGA and HDMI. Is this a lost cause?

If so, are there any reasonably priced monitors that people have had success with with new MacBooks.

Comment: Did you see http://www.mathewinkson.com/2013/03/force-rgb-mode-in-mac-os-x-to-fix-the-picture-quality-of-an-external-monitor ? I'm going to play with that myself tomorrow & see where I get. I've never had any noticeable issues with my Dells, but want to have a look...

Comment: I tried that script but it didn't seem to change anything for me. I can try it again. Thanks!